# Access authenticated page using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, scrape

I'm trying to write a simple scraper to get usage details on my internet account - I've successfully written it using Powershell, but I'd like to move it to Python for ease of use/deployment. If I print r.text (result of POST to login page) I just get the login page form details again.

I think the solution might be something along the lines of using prepare_request? Apologies if I'm missing something super obvious, been about 5 years since I touched python ^^

```
import requests
USERNAME = 'usernamehere'
PASSWORD = 'passwordhere'
loginURL = 'https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/ClientLogin.aspx'
secureURL = 'https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/FibreUsageDetails.aspx'

session = requests.session()
req_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

formdata = {
    'ctl00$MemberToolsContent$txtUsername': USERNAME,
    'ctl00$MemberToolsContent$txtPassword': PASSWORD,
    'ctl00$MemberToolsContent$btnLogin' : 'Login'
}

session.get(loginURL)
r = session.post(loginURL, data=formdata, headers=req_headers, allow_redirects=False)
r2 = session.get(secureURL)
```

I've referenced these threads in my attempts:

[HTTP POST and GET with cookies for authentication in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247054/http-post-and-get-with-cookies-for-authentication-in-python)
[Authentication and python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397375/authentication-and-python-requests)

Powershell script for reference:

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/ClientLogin.aspx' -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable RequestForm
$r.Forms[0].Fields['ctl00$MemberToolsContent$txtUsername'] = "usernamehere"
$r.Forms[0].Fields['ctl00$MemberToolsContent$txtPassword'] = "passwordhere"
$r.Forms[0].Fields['ctl00$MemberToolsContent$btnLogin'] = "Login"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/ClientLogin.aspx' -WebSession $RequestForm -Method POST -Body $r.Forms[0].Fields -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
$response2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/FibreUsageDetails.aspx' -WebSession $RequestForm
```

Comment: It is using hidden values - I am preparing the answer

Comment: Ahhhhh, the Viewstate? I thought that would be automatically handled by using a Session (like the Powershell script). I'll try grabbing the value with BeautifulSoup and passing it in while you're readying the actual answer XD thanks for your help!

Comment: Perfect! I have posted the answer - Found that its not just `VIEWSTATE`, but also `VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and `RadMasterScriptManager_TSM`

Comment: GOT IT! Answer is indeed @Md.Mohsin script below, but the $ in the "MemberToolsContent username/password fields shouldn't be converted to %24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user="xyzmohsin"
passwd="abcpassword"

s=requests.Session()
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"}
s.headers.update(headers)

login_url="https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/ClientLogin.aspx"
r=s.get(login_url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
RadMasterScriptManager_TSM=soup.find(src=re.compile("RadMasterScriptManager_TSM"))['src'].split("=")[-1]
EVENTTARGET=soup.find(id="__EVENTTARGET")['value']
EVENTARGUMENT=soup.find(id="__EVENTARGUMENT")['value']
VIEWSTATE=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']


data={"RadMasterScriptManager_TSM":RadMasterScriptManager_TSM,
"__EVENTTARGET":EVENTTARGET,
"__EVENTARGUMENT":EVENTARGUMENT,
"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
"ctl00_TopMenu_RadMenu_TopNav_ClientState":"",
"ctl00%24MemberToolsContent%24HiddenField_Redirect":"",
"ctl00%24MemberToolsContent%24txtUsername":user,
"ctl00%24MemberToolsContent%24txtPassword":passwd,
"ctl00%24MemberToolsContent%24btnLogin":"Login"}

headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Host":"myaccount.amcom.com.au",
"Origin":"https://myaccount.amcom.com.au",
"Referer":"https://myaccount.amcom.com.au/ClientLogin.aspx"}

r=s.post(login_url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

I don't have the username and password hence the couldn't test the headers in the final post requests. If it doesn't work - then please remove `Host`, `Origin` and `Referer` from the final post requests's headers.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: @Mike Anthony. I have updated the code. Had missed a line earlier.
The one you see above should work fine. Let me know if it helps :-)

Comment: Aha, thanks! Here I was pulling my hair out wondering why it's still not working haha. Testing now

Comment: @Mike Anthony Let me know what happens :-)

Comment: Hmm, r.text contains: "The following error(s) occured whilst attempting to process your Login. </strong><br/>Please ensure that all fields are filled out and in the correct format". I'm comparing the fields I'm sending in powershell vs python now

Comment: @ Mike Anthony Are you trying the code as it is - except the user and passwd? Or did you change anything?

Comment: Code is as-is except for replacing username/password with working values. To test I'm just running "print (r.text)"

Comment: @Mike Anthony Are you sure the username and password is correct and case sensitive? Because the error you are getting in `r.content` is invalid login details error. What happens when you use the same details in Browser?

Comment: Yep I'm sure - the details are copy/pasted from my Powershell script which successfully authenticates :)

Comment: Can you try using the same details in browser and let me know what happens? Also if you can observe to net tab to see if there is any other requests as well - running right after the `post` we are sending

Comment: Found the problem, converting $ to %24 was causing the failure - replacing with $ works perfectly! Thank you so much!!! Sorry I can't mark your answer as useful, less than 15 rep :(

Comment: @Mike Anthony haha no problem. I am glad I could help. Thanks Mike