# Download PDFs using IE/Excel/Python - Links are JSP Queries

Tags: python, excel, jsp, pdf

So I have about 400 documents to download, I do not have direct links to the files. The link format is:

http://domain.com/getCurrentDoc.jsp?property1=1111&property2=2222 and so on.

Please note, LAN credentials are required to access these. When I use IE, I can just right click the link and save as. If I use firefox it prompts me for my LAN username/password, and then works fine.

I have have all the links in an .htm file and an .xlsx file. I don't mind using Excel, but I need a way to enter credentials, and most methods online have links pointing directly to the pdf and don't work for me.

I also don't mind using python, or some other scripting language. I am restricted to Windows 7 and do not have local admin rights on the PC (only affects installation of software or windows settings changes, I can run python scripts and stuff). Worst case I will emulate mouse clicks and use IE if necessary.

Please let me know if you have any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: Extremely similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397375/authentication-and-python-requests

Comment: That example has an HTML form. Mine is a bit different, it does a windows authentication. Anyway, ignoring the authentication for a moment, how would I even do the "get", because I cant just get the url, because the url doesnt point to a file, it is a query.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try some automation software that could record your actions and then repeat them over and over.

Some of these tools are:

- [Jitbit Macro Recoder](https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/) (paid)
- [Macro Recorder](http://www.macro-recorder.com/) (paid)
- [Auto hot key](https://www.autohotkey.com) (free)

Comment: Thanks, this is my last resort. I cannot install autohotkey since I do not have local admin rights on the PC, but if I can't get anything else to work, I might try generating an executable on another PC and then run that.