# Python Requests authentication with proxy for POST call

Tags: python, authentication, post, proxy, python-requests

I am using my company's internet, and I need to access a webpage to scrape data off it.  I am using the Python Requests module.  The page I need to access is done through a POST request.  My company has a proxy.  I can get through the proxy using the proxies flag in requests.post().  However, there is an authentication part which uses cookies, and I can't seem to get through it.  How should I do the authentication part when using a POST request?

I am trying to use the authentication process as described in this thread, but it's not working: 
[Authentication and python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397375/authentication-and-python-requests)

The code is set up this way:

```
import ssl
from MyHtmlParser import MyHTMLParser
from lxml import html 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def authenticate(s, url):
    headers = {'USER_NAME': 'me', 'PASSWORD': 'mypassword', '_Id': 'submit'}
    page=s.get(url)
    soup=bs(page.content)
    value=soup.form.find_all('input')[2]['value']
    headers.update({'value_name':value})
    auth = s.post(url, params=headers, cookies=page.cookies)

post_url_finance = 'https://opsdata<company>com/scripts/finance/finance.exe'
values_finance = {'EMPLOYEE_TOTAL': 'employeeId'}

proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy-<company>.com'}

page = requests.post(post_url_finance, data=values_finance, proxies=proxies) print page.content
```

However, I am getting this error back:

```
$ python postUsingRequests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postUsingRequests.py", line 53, in <module>
    page = requests.post(post_url_finance, data=values_finance, proxies=proxies) 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having seems to be caused by an untrusted SSL certificate.

The quickest fix is setting [`verify=False`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/). Please note that this will cause the certificate not to be verified and expose your application to security risks. But as you mensioned, it is running in a safe network so this is not a serious problem.

Comment: I tried it with verify=False, and I am getting this back:  $ python postUsingRequests.py
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)

Comment: I am expecting a page with a table on it to scrape.  does this mean it's not taking me to that page?

Comment: it seems like if I don't go through authentication, it's not showing me the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = requests.session()
s.auth = {'USER_NAME': '----', 'PASSWORD': '----'}
pageCert = requests.post(post_url_finance, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

I used s.auth with verify=False.  This gave me a response back instead of giving me the SSL error.