# Getting 401 authentication error with Python Requests, wget functions correctly

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to download a zip file from a provider, using wget works fine:

```
wget -c --http-user=MY_UN --http-password=MY_PW "https://datapool.asf.alaska.edu/GRD_MD/SA/S1A_EW_GRDM_1SDH_20151003T040339_20151003T040351_007983_00B2A6_7377.zip"
```

However using the Python Requests library I get 401 errors using the same credentials, does anybody know why that might be, or where to look to begin understanding the problem?

```
url = "https://datapool.asf.alaska.edu/GRD_MD/SA/S1A_EW_GRDM_1SDH_20151003T040339_20151003T040351_007983_00B2A6_7377.zip"    
r = requests.get(url, auth=("MY_UN", "MY_PW"), stream = True)
```

I should mention that I have quadruple checked the details, and they are correct on both.  Is there an alternative method in Python?

In the mean time I have had to spawn a wget using the os package:

```
os.system("wget -c --http-user=MY_UN--http-password=MY_PW 'https://datapool.asf.alaska.edu/GRD_MD/SA/S1A_EW_GRDM_1SDH_20151003T040339_20151003T040351_007983_00B2A6_7377.zip'")
```

Comment: does your password contains backslashes? you could try to pass the `r` prefix to your string.

Comment: No I'm afraid not, just characters and numbers, same for my user name, except that the UN has a . in it.  Good idea though, are you thinking of escaping the string?

Comment: It looks like they are doing oauth. This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397375/authentication-and-python-requests

Comment: With requests, your example is explicitly trying to authenticate with HTTP Basic Authentication.  However, `wget` supports multiple types of authentication when passing `http-user`/`--http-password`.  It is likely your app is using a different type like Digest or NTLM.  That would explain why your example in wget works while requests failed.  The docs for requests have examples for different authentication here: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue, I solved it using an HTTPDigestAuth instead of an HTTPBasicAuth.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('mylogin', 'mypassword'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the following:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False # to bypass a proxy
r = session.get(url, verify=False) # or if there is a certificate do verify='file.cer'
```

Comment: Try to put login and password into variables and print them out to see if they still look the same